# Datatables filter from server side

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, server-side

I using datatables and column filter add-on to display and filter data from database. I implement checkbox for multi selection filtering. All I can do is to predefined values for checkbox filters, but I need checkbox filters values from database.

```
jQuery('#tabela').dataTable({
                   "oLanguage": {
                   "sSearch": "Search:",
                   "sInfoFiltered": '' 
                    },
                   "bProcessing": true,
                   "bServerSide": true,
                   "sServerMethod": "GET",
                   "sAjaxSource": "server.php",
                   "fnServerParams": function(aoData) {
                                     aoData.push({"name" : "more_data", 
                                                 "value" : "my_value"})
                          },
                   "bJQueryUI": true
                   }).columnFilter({
                              aoColumns: [
                                         { type: "checkbox", 
                                           values: ["Filter Cola 1", 
                                           "FIlter Cola 2", "FIlter Cola 3"]},
                                         {},
                                         { type: "checkbox",
                                           values: ["Filter Colc 1", 
                                           "FIlter Colc 2","FIlter Colc 3"]}
                              ]
                    });
```

How to setup checkbox filter values from server side?

Comment: Have you tried to implement this at all?  Have you run into problems implementing the server-side logic?

Comment: Yes, I have imeplemented server side logic, I retreive data from server. All that work fine. But I don't know how to set checkbox values depending on results from server.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#tabela').dataTable({
                   "oLanguage": {
                   "sSearch": "Search:",
                   "sInfoFiltered": '' 
                    },
                   "bProcessing": true,
                   "bServerSide": true,
                   "sServerMethod": "GET",
                   "sAjaxSource": "server.php",
                   "fnServerParams": function(aoData) {
                                     aoData.push({"name" : "more_data", 
                                                 "value" : "my_value"})
                          },
                   "bJQueryUI": true
                   }).columnFilter({
                              aoColumns: [  { type: 'checkbox',
                        data: "{'Pending':'Pending','Complete':'Complete'}"// use like this type  i am just giving an idea use with your data it will work i used this way and it works

                                }

                              ]
                    });
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I didn't understan. That's not work for me. I need checkbox values for filtering result in table. For example: I have checkbox value: Smith, whene it is checked, only rows that contain name Smith will bi displayed.

Comment: thanks for response, but this can't help because this is example about sorting. I need filtering example.